Tomcat10 webapp deployed several times
It seems that my webapp application is deployed several times either at tomcat startup or if I deployed a war file through tomcat manager.
At startup in catalina.out:
23/08/2024 13:36:42,167+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Déploiement de l'archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/StatHoro.war] de l'application web
2024-08-23 13:36:46 [main] INFO  com.gerbier.connectic.stathoro.servlet.SchedulerServlet - Initializing Quartz Scheduler.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2024-08-23 13:36:46 [main] INFO  com.gerbier.connectic.stathoro.servlet.SchedulerServlet - Job scheduled to run daily at 6pm.
2024-08-23 13:36:46 [main] INFO  com.gerbier.connectic.stathoro.servlet.SchedulerServlet - Quartz Scheduler started.
**23/08/2024 13:36:46,594+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Le déploiement de l'archive de l'application web [/opt/tomcat/webapps/StatHoro.war] s'est terminé en [4 425] ms**
23/08/2024 13:36:46,599+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire d'application web [/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager]
23/08/2024 13:36:46,672+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Le déploiement du répertoire [/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager] de l'application web s'est terminé en [73] ms
23/08/2024 13:36:46,673+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire d'application web [/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
23/08/2024 13:36:46,719+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Le déploiement du répertoire [/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] de l'application web s'est terminé en [46] ms
23/08/2024 13:36:46,723+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire d'application web [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples]
23/08/2024 13:36:47,056+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Le déploiement du répertoire [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples] de l'application web s'est terminé en [333] ms
23/08/2024 13:36:47,059+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire d'application web [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
23/08/2024 13:36:47,097+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Le déploiement du répertoire [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] de l'application web s'est terminé en [37] ms
23/08/2024 13:36:47,097+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire d'application web [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs]
23/08/2024 13:36:47,137+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Le déploiement du répertoire [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs] de l'application web s'est terminé en [40] ms
2024-08-23 13:36:49 [main] INFO  com.gerbier.connectic.stathoro.servlet.SchedulerServlet - Initializing Quartz Scheduler.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2024-08-23 13:36:49 [main] INFO  com.gerbier.connectic.stathoro.servlet.SchedulerServlet - Job scheduled to run daily at 6pm.
2024-08-23 13:36:49 [main] INFO  com.gerbier.connectic.stathoro.servlet.SchedulerServlet - Quartz Scheduler started.
**23/08/2024 13:36:49,630+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Déploiement de l'archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/StatHoro.war] de l'application web**
2024-08-23 13:36:51 [main] INFO  com.gerbier.connectic.stathoro.servlet.SchedulerServlet - Initializing Quartz Scheduler.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2024-08-23 13:36:52 [main] INFO  com.gerbier.connectic.stathoro.servlet.SchedulerServlet - Job scheduled to run daily at 6pm.
2024-08-23 13:36:52 [main] INFO  com.gerbier.connectic.stathoro.servlet.SchedulerServlet - Quartz Scheduler started.
**23/08/2024 13:36:52,114+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Le déploiement de l'archive de l'application web [/opt/tomcat/webapps/StatHoro.war] s'est terminé en [2 483] ms**
23/08/2024 13:36:52,115+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire d'application web [/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager]
23/08/2024 13:36:52,155+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Le déploiement du répertoire [/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager] de l'application web s'est terminé en [39] ms
23/08/2024 13:36:52,155+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire d'application web [/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
23/08/2024 13:36:52,189+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Le déploiement du répertoire [/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] de l'application web s'est terminé en [34] ms
23/08/2024 13:36:52,190+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire d'application web [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples]
23/08/2024 13:36:52,365+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
23/08/2024 13:36:52,367+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
23/08/2024 13:36:52,368+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@116c6cf5')
23/08/2024 13:36:52,375+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Le déploiement du répertoire [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples] de l'application web s'est terminé en [185] ms
23/08/2024 13:36:52,376+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire d'application web [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs]
23/08/2024 13:36:52,409+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Le déploiement du répertoire [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs] de l'application web s'est terminé en [33] ms
23/08/2024 13:36:52,418+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Démarrage du gestionnaire de protocole ["http-nio-8081"]
23/08/2024 13:36:52,456+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Démarrage du gestionnaire de protocole ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
23/08/2024 13:36:52,476+1100 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Le démarrage du serveur a pris [10436] millisecondes


With tomcat manager (these is log of a job that is registered at startup)
2024-08-23 13:32:21 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] INFO  com.gerbier.connectic.stathoro.servlet.SchedulerServlet - Initializing Quartz Scheduler.
2024-08-23 13:32:21 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] INFO  com.gerbier.connectic.stathoro.servlet.SchedulerServlet - Job scheduled to run daily at 6pm.
2024-08-23 13:32:21 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] INFO  com.gerbier.connectic.stathoro.servlet.SchedulerServlet - Quartz Scheduler started.
2024-08-23 13:32:31 [Catalina-utility-2] INFO  com.gerbier.connectic.stathoro.servlet.SchedulerServlet - Initializing Quartz Scheduler.
2024-08-23 13:32:31 [Catalina-utility-2] INFO  com.gerbier.connectic.stathoro.servlet.SchedulerServlet - Job scheduled to run daily at 6pm.
2024-08-23 13:32:31 [Catalina-utility-2] INFO  com.gerbier.connectic.stathoro.servlet.SchedulerServlet - Quartz Scheduler started.

It seems to be related to thread but all my readings didn't helped me.
My server.xml file looks like :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">
 
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
               />

    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
        scheme="https" sslProtocol="TLS"
               >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />

    <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateFile="conf/cert.pem"
                         certificateKeyFile="conf/privkey.pem"
             certificateChainFile="conf/chain.pem" />
        </SSLHostConfig>

    </Connector>

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>

      <Host name="xxxxxxxxxxx"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNapespaceAware="false">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="stathoro_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSZ}t %h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />   
    <Context path="" docBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps/StatHoro" debug="9" reloadable="true" />
      </Host>

    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>

Any help greatly appreciated ! :)
Sylvain
P.S : 1st post on stackoverflow, sorry for eventuals mistakes.

Little upgrade : I don't have this behaviour in my dev environment (Eclipse + embedded tomcat) ...
Anybody ?
